# "No caching mode page present" when USB flash disk attached

Tags: usb, mount, ntfs

When attaching a USB flash disk (NTFS formatted) to a laptop with Ubuntu Server 12.04 on board, I get following messages:

```
[ 3572.355603] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[ 3572.355640] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3572.361599] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[ 3572.361636] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

I get them right in the terminal, so that I should press `Ctrl+C` to proceed with working (entering commands).
Is it normal or do I have to setup Caching mode somehow?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the write cache is enabled for all devices you plug into the laptop or the `/etc/fstab` file has the option `async`. Something like:

```
[...]
/dev/sdb1    /media/USB    auto        async    0   0
/dev/sdb1    /media/USB    auto        default    0   0
[...]
```

(Note: `default` option is the same as `rw`, `suid`, `dev`, `exec`, `auto`, `nouser`, and **`async`**

or activated in `hdparm`:

```
sudo /sbin/hdparm -I /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
[...]
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache <-------
       *    Look-ahead
       *    WRITE_VERIFY command
[...]
Checksum: correct
```

This is the default option. So, it seems that your USB don't support this caracteristic which triggers the `strout` warning. You can disable it replacing the lines in `fstab` or issuing `sudo hdparm -W 0 /dev/sdb`.