# Ubuntu install fails,

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

Dear more experienced Linux users!
I have several PC-s on which I can run Ubuntu (or some other distro of linux) without a problem, but on  one of my machines the installation fails every time.
It's an old P4 Asrock 775 DualVsta, 2gb ram, P4 661 cpu, Nvidia 8600gt silent pipeII gpu, Win 8.1 installed. A few months ago I tried to install Ubuntu on this nasty machine, but during installation (or startup in the try without install mode) the progress bar stopped and after that nothing happened. Tried installing from USB and from DVD too -nothing- the boot disks and drives worked flawlessly on other machines.

Now several months later I replaced the old IDE drive with an 1TB sata one, and I tought its time to try installing Ubuntu on this one again. I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.3 created a bootable stick with UniversalUSBinstaller, tried it out in another PC (Win 8.1 installed too) no problems, the try without insall mode starts as it should (no caching mode page found message- but skips it and starts). 
Then comes the harder part (for me at least) plug it in the problematic pc, boot from the stick, select try without install, and then I get the no caching mode page found message and it stops there, nothing happens anymore. I searched BIOS for UEFI settings (or legacy) but I couldn't find anything like that. The legacy mode is enabled in usb settings. Tried to make another stick-same results. 
Now I simply don't know what to do. 
I really appreciate any kind of help
Thanks!

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the error page and upload it on imgur.com then provide us with the link here. We need to see what the error message is.

Comment: I don't really know how to make screenshots in BIOS, but its only 3 rows so I can write it down. :First row:  probe failed. Second row: [7.959754]] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No caching mode page found Trird row: [7.959863] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through ___Thats all and If I remember correctly the message is the same on other machines but it quickly disappears and the system starts immediately.

Comment: Does this help you? http://askubuntu.com/questions/129402/no-caching-mode-page-present-when-usb-flash-disk-attached

Comment: It seems that this message is different (mine is:"...found" and this is:" ...present"). And as I said I am not experienced with Linux operation systems in general (I can open the terminal and run basic commands in it but thats it...). My main concern is not about this message (in my opinion) because as I said it appears on other machines too and other PCs simply skip it and start, but this one is stuck there. I pressed the Ctrl+c combination but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution. I pressed the Tab button (during boot) to open Grub, and with the nomodeset command the system finally started.